# Mix cython and cmake extensions in python setuptools

Tags: python, cmake, setuptools

I have a python package with the following setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    # ...


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    # ...


extensions = [
    CMakeExtension("cmake_extension", "path-to-sources"),
    Extension("cython_extension", ["file.pyx"]),
]


setup(
    # ...
    ext_modules=extensions,
    # ...
)
```

I would like to know if I can call `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and build each extension with the appropriate builder.

I am aware of the `cmdclass` setup function argument but did not find a way to specify that `build_ext` should be used for the cython extensions and `CMakeBuild` for the cmake ones.

Note that each extension is building fine with the correct builder class (and the `cmdclass` argument).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I found:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    # ...


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    # ...


if sys.argv[1] == "build_ext":
    c_ext = [Extension(...)]
elif sys.argv[1] == "build_cmk":
    c_ext = [CMakeExtension(...)]
else:
    raise NotImplementedError


setup(
    # ...
    ext_modules=cythonize(c_ext),
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext, "build_cmk": CMakeBuild},
    # ...
)
```

And then run:

```sh
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python setup.py build_cmk --inplace
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot is to ensure `CMakeBuild` detects the type of extension and reverts back to the original `build_ext` if the Extension is not an instance of `CMakeExtension`.